# Angular removing anything after '=' in query string from URL

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get query strings to work in my Angular setup, but it is behaving weirdly.

When i go to a URL like this:

http://localhost:3000/?query=test

The URL changes and removes anything after the '=' to end up with:

http://localhost:3000/?query

Has anyone had this problem before?

I am currently using Angular UI Router with defined states and HTML 5 mode.  I have also tried specifying the query parameter in the route as below:

```
.state('home', {
        url: '/?referrer',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/home/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
})
```

UPDATED........

OK.  In my controller i had this:

```
var referrerURL = $location.search('referrer');
```

Removing this, fixes the issue.  Why would this cause the problem?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you provided some code. Are you using `$location` anywhere in your app? What about routing?

Comment: I've edited my question.  Sorry about that.  I am also using $location yes injected into certain controllers, but only being used to grab certain segments of the URL on certain pages.

Comment: Read the fine manual ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search ~ *"Change search part when called with parameter"*. It's only a *getter* when you call it with no arguments

Comment: Also, seeing as it's part of your state configuration, why not just use `var referrerURL = $stateParams.referrer`?

Comment: Check that the state variables in your $scope before and after your call that you deleted are still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your input.

I fixed this by changing my controller to use:

```
var referrerURL = $location.search().referrer;
```

Answer (score 1):

For `$location.search()` method, you should use it like this:

$location.search('key','value').

If you don't set the value, it would be "true" by default.

More information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search)

Comment: I think OP is attempting to retrieve the value, not set it so it should be `var referrerURL = $location.search().referrer` or even more simply `$stateParams.referrer`